# Cannot reload second level routes in Express (running Angular app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I can reload first level routes with these settings, but not second level routes. The 'game' route defined below for example cannot be reloaded, but the login route can.

I have added `<base href="/">` in index.html.

Angular router.js (using angular-ui-router):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: templateUrlRoot + 'root.html',
        controller: 'gameListController',
        title: 'ManRPG'
    })
    .state('game', {
        url: '/game/:gameId',
        templateUrl: templateUrlRoot + 'game.html',
        controller: 'gameController',
        title: 'Game'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: templateUrlRoot + 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        title: 'Login'
    })
```

Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ... other routes, etcetera

app.use('/api', router);

// Send the angular app, make sure that index.html is served first
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/app' ));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/app/index.html'); 
})
```

Any help/advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour occured because my some of my files were included without a starting "/". So what I did was changing:

```
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="/js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

And this solved my problem.